# How to place an image after Nth number of posts in query_posts

Tags: query-posts

I am using the following code to print out the last 8 published post in columns of 3
so 3 column and 3 rows :

```
<?php
  $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'post',
               'posts_per_page' => 8,
               'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
               );
  query_posts($args);
  $x = 0;
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    

    <?php if($x == 2) { ?>
    <div class="portfolio_list_box portfolio_list_last">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="portfolio_list_box">
    <?php } ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-home-portfolio'); ?></a>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!--//portfolio_list_box-->  

    <?php if($x == 2) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; $x = -1; } ?>

  <?php $x++; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

now I want to place an image after 5th post . which is row 2 column 3. 
I modified this code for so many times but I can not get that image to show up after post 5 only.

I added this :

```
<?php if($x == 2) { ?>
    <div class="portfolio_list_box portfolio_list_last">
    <?php } elseif($x == 5) { ?>
 // image 
<?php } else { ?>
```

but does not work . I really appreciate if someone help me to figure out this. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple nested `if` statements can create a mess you might look into using  a `switch` for this case.

Something like:

```
  //your $args
  $the_switch_query = new WP_Query($args);

  while ( $the_switch_query ->have_posts() ) : $the_switch_query ->the_post(); 

  $query_number = $the_switch_query->current_post + 1; //count them

       switch ($query_number){

             case 1;
             echo "post one";
             break;

             case 5;
             echo "post five";
             break;

            // more cases

            default:
            echo "default";
        }
       //rest of your stuff
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am not even sure have to use this code , is it possible to help me a little bit more ? thanks

Comment: This might help, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 1):

this is really just a php question. it never reaches 5 because you reset $x to -1 when it's equal to 2

```
<?php if($x == 2) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; $x = -1; } ?>
```

Comment: if I change the $x=-1 to any value, the columns will be apart